# ReactiveRedisTemplate delete not delete all keys with publisher

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-data-redis

I have problem with removing keys from Redis in reactive way - only one key is removed. But find query return multiple results.

```
redisTemplate.delete(redisTemplate.keys(PREFIX + STAR_PATTERN))
                .subscribe(count -> LOGGER.info("Removed {}", count));
```

this code only remove one key (last one);
But when I change this code to:

```
redisTemplate.keys(PREFIX + STAR_PATTERN)
                .flatMap(redisTemplate::delete)
                .subscribe(key -> LOGGER.info("Removed from cache {}", key))
```

works fine.

Why first code not removing all keys ?

Comment: can you confirm the log for the first snippet did appear as "Removed 1"?

Comment: Yes. It shows „Removed 1”. I have also tried how many keys query retrun values (by collectList and block) it shows around 10 key. And delete always remove one

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. [`ReactiveRedisTemplate.delete(Publisher)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/eafcb331d818f99342588af2f09cc2bb8c7e169d/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveRedisTemplate.java#L353) considers only the first returned key to be deleted, not the subsequent keys.

I filed [DATAREDIS-913](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-913) to track the issue.

Comment: This is marked as closed as of Jan 10, 2019